# Easiest and the chepest way to touch up missing paint patches on 2000 Chevy Cavalier

Tags: maintenance, chevrolet, paint, paint-scratches, cavalier

I have a chevy 2000 cavalier. I started noticing patches (pictures posted below) on the top and in front of the car. I'm not sure if it needs touch up paint or waxing (I'm a total illiterate when it comes to car maintenance). Wondering if you guys can guide me to fix it myself. 
I searched through a [couple of sites](http://www.automotivetouchup.com/touch-up-paint/chevrolet/2000/cavalier/) that sell touch up paint for this car (Cayenne Red Metallic I think?) Do I need anything else to buy to apply the paint? (Like spray bottle, paint brush etc.)

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Are those white edges loose paint?  Can you lift them with your fingernail?  Those definitely don't look like scratches.  Was you car parked under anything that leaks solvents?

Comment: @BobCross I will definitely try to lift it and post back results. about the second question, my car is parked in a lot with no cover. It's never been parked under any structure that leaks solvents (99.9% sure but..)

Comment: It looks as though the clear coat is pealing, except for the top, where it has been missing clear coat long enough to fade the paint. There is no easy fix here.

Comment: @Paulster2 Can you approximately tell me how much it might cost if I take it to the shop (and also the dealer)? Thanks.

Comment: It's caused by prolonged exposure to excessive heat. I see this a lot with old metallic paint jobs.

Comment: I posted an answer on how to do it the right way, but you may be able to get away with running a buffer over the spot to get rid of the pealing and then spraying on a few coats of clear gloss (remember to buff again after a few days to smooth it out).

Comment: There is no way I could give you even an approximate estimate on what it would cost. This is because it ranges widely by where you live and the quality of the paint job you'll want to achieve. I'd suggest taking it to several body shops and get some estimates. The dealership, while providing a quality paint job, will charge a lot more than a local shop. You can get the estimates for free, though it will cost you a little bit of your time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a brush even if paint can is sitting in hot water; brush strokes are inevitable.
Sand bonnet to smooth surface using ever finer grades of wet & dry sandpaper. Clean off with wax & grease remover. Prop up bonnet to make level. Spray with acrylic primer- dry-resand-reapply-sand-again use wax & grease remover.Topcoat with acrylic paint of chosen colour. Spray cans are fine. Colour code to be found on compliance plate. All details of
grades of sandpaper to use; application; drying times etc. are to be found on side of
primer/paint spray cans.N.B. make sure surfaces and environment are dust free.

Skill level - anyone can do it.